# Swift tableview Cell label change Text by button tag

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

I Have Create one button , and Two label On tableview Cell , When click on button Then change tableview label text 
Here is my code

```
func buttonLike_ww(sender: AnyObject?) {
        var tag:NSInteger = sender!.tag;

        tag_last_button_clicked = tag;


        // found table
        let cell = TableViewCell_trandingjive(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"Cell")
        cell.label_dislike.text = "20"
        cell.label_like.text = "50"

    }
```

Comment: Could your please try to describe your problem with proper english ? I'd like to help you here but I can't understand your question.

Comment: tableview label text change by index number
I have Create one button And button set tag set index.row and set Click Event "buttonLike_ww" then Click on button change tableview label by button tag @dehlen Please help me

Comment: You basically want to change the label of the current index once the current cell button tapped? @user3899589

Comment: One question, do you have XIB file or your using regular cell? cause I have a really good solution for both. @user3899589

Answer (score 2):

```
func buttonLike_ww(sender: AnyObject?) {
        let tag:NSInteger = sender!.tag;
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: tag, inSection: 0)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell.label_dislike.text = "20"
        cell.label_like.text = "50"

}
```

Basically what you do is get the tag from the button (which is the indexPath of the UITableViewCell if I got you right). Then get a reference on the cell and change the labels to the text accordingly.

You made the mistake in your approach that you didn't got a reference on the cell but you created a new one. 
Also the above code only works if you got only one section. If you got more than one section you need to know not only the row but the section too.

In this case you can go with this approach:

```
func buttonLike_ww(sender: AnyObject?) {
var position: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(position) {
        let section = indexPath.section
        let row = indexPath.row
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: section)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell.label_dislike.text = "20"
        cell.label_like.text = "50"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can change the current cell label when the current cell button tapped.

First, we need to identify the cell by providing it to the method. Like this, make sure this is in your UIButton Method of the cell.

```
func ButtonTapped(cell: UITableViewCell){
        cell.label_dislike.text = "20"
        cell.label_like.text = "50"
 }
```

Also if you have custom cell with XIB file, you change the `UITableViewCell` to `CustomTableViewCell`.

If you want to get the current index from your data array, you set two variable in you methods.

```
//Get Current Index of you Cell and Match it with your Data Array if
let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(cell.center)
let selectedCell = dataForCell[(indexPath?.row)!] // Change it to you data array ===> dataForCell[(indexPath?.row)!]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Custom TableViewCell with a xib this code might work best for you. Swift 4

```
func buttonLike_ww(sender: AnyObject?) {

    let tag:NSInteger = sender.tag
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: tag, section: 0)

    let cell = TableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.label_dislike.text = "20"
    cell.label_like.text = "50"


}
```